# PHP Change of object class

Tags: php, class, oop

i use classes for some typical MySQL queries, like getting specific users, news etc. And afterwards I call function `query()`, which calls mysqli class and query and returns the query like this:

```
class Users {
  [...]
  public function query() {
    $mysql = new mysqli([...]);
    $mysql->query($this->query);
    return $mysql;
  }
}
```

When I use it for ex. in `$variable` like:

```
$variable = new Users();
$variable->setNew($params)->query();
```

I have still stored object of Users in `$variable`. Is there any way to automatically 'update' the variable to be object of `mysqli_result` (in this case or different class in simillar situation) without using `$variable = $variable->setNew($params)->query();`?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a one liner:

```
$variable = (new Users())->setNew($params)->query();
```

`$variable` now contains the return of `query()`

Comment: Thanks, but when It will be more complicated (like 3 or 4 classes in the sequence), will it work when I 'stop it' in the middle? Like:

`$var = (new Users())->callClassA();`
`$var->callClassB;`

Comment: @Gomi I'm not sure if I understand, can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, I sent it early. Example is above.

Comment: It depends what you return in `callClassA()`. If the return of `callClassA()` has a property/method `callClassB` it works

Comment: In `CallClassA()` it would return `new A();` and similarly in `CallClassB()`. Is this possible?

Comment: if class A contains a method called `CallClassB` it will work yes.